# Changing a textbox to have the values of other textboxes until edited

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make it so that when one textbox, a dropdownlist and another textbox are edited that two other textboxes are edited automatically as well to incluse the sum of those three elements. I got this working but now I want to make it so that when the latter textbox is edited manually it STOPS getting updated automatically by any of the other textboxes changing.

Here is what I've tried:

```
function DescChanged() {
            desc = document.getElementById("Txb_Description");
            input = document.getElementById("Txb_WebArtName");
            kortinput = document.getElementById("KortBesc");
            langinput = document.getElementById("LangBesc");
            merk = document.getElementById("Brand");
            bestelnr = document.getElementById("Txb_ArticleOrderNr");

            merdesbes = merk.options[merk.selectedIndex].text + " " + desc.value + " " + bestelnr.value;
            desbes = desc.value + " " + bestelnr.value;
            input.value = merk.options[merk.selectedIndex].text + " " + desc.value + " " + bestelnr.value;
            if (merk.options[merk.selectedIndex].text == "--") {
                input.value = desc.value + " " + bestelnr.value;
                if (kortinput.value == desbesold.value || isEmptyOrSpaces(kortinput.value)) {
                    kortinput.value = desc.value + " " + bestelnr.value;
                    desbesold = kortinput.value;
                }
                if (langinput.value == desbesold.value || isEmptyOrSpaces(langinput.value)) {
                    langinput.value = desc.value + " " + bestelnr.value;
                    desbesold = langinput.value;
                }
            }
            else { 
                if (kortinput.value = merdesbesold.value || isEmptyOrSpaces(kortinput.value)) {
                    kortinput.value = merdesbes.value;
                    merdesbesold.value = kortinput.value;

                }
                if (langinput.value = merdesbesold.value || isEmptyOrSpaces(langinput.value)) {
                    langinput.value = merdesbes.value;
                    merdesbesold.value = langinput.value;
                }
            }
        }
```

However it seems that the
`if (kortinput.value == desbesold.value || isEmptyOrSpaces(kortinput.value))`
is never hit, which I find strange, as it is empty, meaning it should be caught by the isEmptyOrSpaces. Any idea why this wouldn't work?

Comment: Not sure why you tagged this with C#, it's clearly JavaScript. I've corrected if for you.

Comment: Force of habit, thanks